# AX 2012 Form control and calculation

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Hi I am very new to AX 2012 development, can you help me calculate 2 fields in the form. For example `CurrentKM` and `ActualKM`. I need to display the difference of these two fields in a third field using calculation 
`KMDiff = ActualKM - CurrentKM`.
How can I achieve this on the form level? Appreciate if someone can support me in this.

Comment: Please check the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Make controls auto declared, so You can reference them by name. Control property autodeclaration
Expand + at data entry control. On methods node right click, Override method, modified. 
There fetch currently entered data by realValue method. Control3.realValue(Control1.realValue()-Control2.realValue());
This is strictly by form controls, if these are fields in table, then its different.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider to add a bit more information to your answer. I think I understand your basic idea, but for a beginner like the OP, the answer is hard to understand. You may also want to take a look at [answer] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Display` method to do this. here an example.

***Step 1:***: Declare a real variable for example `real ShowAmount`.

```
public class FormRun extends ObjectRun
{
    real ShowAmount;
}
```

***Step 2:*** Create a `Display` method like this

```
display real CalcAmount()
{
    ShowAmount = 180 - 10; //Replace this static values for your calc.

    return ShowAmount;
}
```

***Step 3:*** Add in desing `RealEdit`. In `DataMethod` property set your `Dysplay` method name.

[image]

***Step 4:*** Execute form and you can see the value.

[image]